# for vs foreach vs while which is faster for iterating through arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, foreach

which one  is the fastest for iterating through arrays in php? or does another exist which is also faster for iterating through arrays?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Even if there is any kind of difference, that difference will be so small it won't matter at all.

If you have, say, one query to the database, it'll take so long compared to the loop iterating over the results that the eternal debate of `for` vs `foreach` vs `while` will not change a thing -- at least if you have a reasonable amount of data.

So, use :

- whatever you like
- whatever fits your programming standard
- whatever is best suited for your code/application

There will be plenty of other things you could/should optimize before thinking about that kind of micro-optimization.

And if you really want some numbers *(even if it's just for fun)*, you can make some benchmark and see the results in practice.

Comment: What the..?^^ I did not know that a winserver with ASP is that faster than a unix system...

Comment: Arrays kan beome quite a burden when it comes to iterating through enormous sets of data. Let's say you would iterate recursively through a huge pile of arrays: PHP would copy every single array into its memory as a new one so the memory usage could potentionally exponentionally explode. This might happen when you would be iterating through arrays with over 100.000 heavy filled nested arrays.

Answer (score 9):

For me I pick my loop based on this:

```
foreach
```

Use when iterating through an array whose length is (or can be) unknown.

```
for
```

Use when iterating through an array whose length is set, or, when you need a counter.

```
while
```

Use when you're iterating through an array with the express purpose of finding, or triggering a certain flag.

Now it's true, you can use a FOR loop like a FOREACH loop, by using count($array)... so ultimately it comes down to your personal preference/style.

Comment: you can also add a count to you foreach by using something like foreach($array as $key => $value){ //code here }

Comment: `while` loops can also be useful for complex algorithms using an array of associative keys (or unsequential keys if you remove elements in the arrays) and for which you need to compare the current value with the previous/next value. You can copy to the previous value into a variable with a `foreach` loop, but you cannot use `prev()` or `next()` functions because the `foreach` loops don't keep a reference to the internal array pointer.

Answer (score 6):

In general there is no applicable speed differences between the three functions.

To provide benchmark results to demonstrate the efficiency of varying methods used to iterate over an array from `1 to 10,000`.

Benchmark results of varying PHP versions: https://3v4l.org/a3Jn4

```
while $i++: 0.00077605247497559 sec
for $i++: 0.00073003768920898 sec
foreach: 0.0004420280456543 sec
while current, next: 0.024288892745972 sec
while reset, next: 0.012929201126099 sec
do while next: 0.011449098587036  sec //added after terminal benchmark
while array_shift: 0.36452603340149 sec
while array_pop: 0.013902902603149 sec
```

Takes into consideration individual calls for `count` with `while` and `for`

```
$values = range(1, 10000);
$l = count($values);
$i = 0;
while($i<$l){
   $i++;
}

$l = count($values);
for($i=0;$i<$l;$i++){
}

foreach($values as $val){
}
```

---

The below examples using `while`, demonstrate how it would be used less efficiently during iteration.

When functionally iterating over an array and maintaining the current position; `while` becomes much less efficient, as `next()` and `current()` is called during the iteration.

```
while($val = current($values)){
    next($values);
}
```

If the current positioning of the array is not important, you can call `reset()` or `current()` prior to iteration.

```
$value = reset($values);
while ($value) {
    $value = next($values);
}
```

`do ... while` is an alternative syntax that can be used, also in conjunction with calling `reset()` or `current()` prior to iteration and by moving the `next()` call to the end of the iteration.

```
$value = current($values);
do{
}while($value = next($values));
```

`array_shift` can also be called during the iteration, but that negatively impacts performance greatly, due to `array_shift` re-indexing the array each time it is called.

```
while($values){
   array_shift($values);
}
```

Alternatively `array_reverse` can be called prior to iteration, in conjunction with calling `array_pop`. This will avoid the impact from re-indexing when calling `array_shift`.

```
$values = array_reverse($values);
while($values) {
   array_pop($values);
}
```

In conclusion, the speed of `while`, `for`, and `foreach` should not be the question, but rather what is done within them to maintain positioning of the array.

Terminal Tests run on PHP 5.6.20 x64 NTS CLI:  [image: Test Results]

Answer (score 2):

Correctly used, while is the fastest, as it can have only one check for every iteration, comparing one $i with another $max variable, and no additional calls before loop (except setting $max) or during loop (except $i++; which is inherently done in any loop statement).

When you start misusing it (like while(list..) ) you're better off with foreach of course, as every function call will not be as optimized as the one included in foreach (because that one is pre-optimized).

Even then, array_keys() gives you the same usability as foreach, still faster.
And beyond that, if you're into 2d-arrays, a home-made 2d_array_keys will enable you to use while all the way in a much faster way then foreach can be used (just try and tell the next foreach within the first foreach, that the last foreach had <2d_array_keys($array)> as keys  --- ).

Besides, all questions related to first or last item of a loop using a while($i

And

```
while ($people_care_about_optimization!==true){
 echo "there still exists a better way of doing it and there's no reason to use any other one";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a benchmark test.

There is no major "performance" difference, because the differences are located inside the logic.

- You use foreach for array iteration,
  without integers as keys.
- You use for for array iteration with
  integers as keys.
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that prefetching a lot of `mysqli_result` into a comfortable array can raise the question whether it is better to use `for`/`foreach`/`while` to cycle that array, but it's the wrong question about a bad solution that waste a lot of RAM.

So do not prefere this:

```
function funny_query_results($query) {
    $results = $GLOBALS['mysqli']->query($query);
    $rows = [];
    while( $row = $results->fetch_object() ) {
        $rows[] = $results;
    }
    return $rows;
}

$rows = funny_query_results("SELECT ...");
foreach($rows as $row) { // Uh... What should I use? foreach VS for VS while?
    echo $row->something;
}
```

The direct way getting one-by-one every `mysql_result` in a simple `while` is a lot more optimized:

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT ...");
while( $row = $results->fetch_object() ) {
    echo $row->something;
}
```