# Which is faster and uses less resources in php?

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [for vs foreach vs while which is faster for iterating through arrays in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852242/for-vs-foreach-vs-while-which-is-faster-for-iterating-through-arrays-in-php)

`For each` and `while`, which of these is faster, recommended, and what are their resource usages like?

Comment: If this is a true concern, I suspect you're using the wrong language  and platform.

Comment: @amphetamachine, these wheels are carrying most of top top rated sites, lol :) The key word here is "true concern". The thing you really need is not a program language, but a programmer. endangered species novadays...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foreach` is optimized for iteration over collections. That's a fancy way of saying that it works best (and fastest) when you use it with arrays (and as of PHP5, objects). You can use `while()` to get the same effect as a foreach, but its not as efficient since you need to call `list()` inside the `while` loop.

`foreach($array as $key => $value)` written with a `while` is `while(list($key,$value) = each($array))`. You can see the number of extra calls that are needed.

Comment: +1. The big downside of `foreach` is that you can't navigate within the collection, and you don't know when you've reached its end.

Comment: The `foreach` loop will perform the same calls, only it is hidden from your eyes. Shorter code is not necessarily faster (although it might be, in this case).

Comment: @Pekka not that big. And, still, the question itself is stupid one, you know.

Comment: @Col well, it *is* a big downside if you need to navigate inside the array. But I agree, the performance differences are really irrelevant

Comment: @Pekka dunno what do you mean by "navigate", but if it's not "iterate" then foreach is just wrong tool for this

Answer (score 1):

i think they should have the same speed.
i prefer foreach because its safer.

Answer (score 1):

That may depend on how you use them exactly. You can choose to pass an array by reference to the `foreach` loop. In that case there will not be made a copy of the entire array. Optimizations like this probably have more effect than choosing between `foreach` and `while`.