# What is the difference between iterating a result set object with a foreach versus calling mysqli_fetch_assoc() in a while loop?

Tags: php, while-loop, foreach, mysqli, result-object

I have a bit of dilemma, In PHP both foreach loop and while loop seem to do exactly the same thing in this situation:

```
foreach ($execute->result as $item) {
    echo $item['user_pass'] . '<br />';
}
```

AND

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($execute->result)) {
    echo $row['user_pass'] . '<br />';
}
```

- My question is are there any real differences?
- When would be better to use one over another or is it fine to use both?
- Does any of these two give you potential greater flexibility?

Comment: You can iterate over every collection using `while`, but it does not mean you should do it. I would always prefer `foreach` for collections and `while` loops for something else

Answer (score 5):

In this case they're exactly equivalent. The `mysqli_result` implements the `Traversable` interface (as documented here: http://www.php.net/mysqli_result ) so it can be iterated using a `foreach` loop as well.

I suppose that, internally, calling `foreach` on a `mysqli_result` object performs the calls to `mysqli_fetch_assoc` as well.

I don't think it makes any difference to use the first method or the second; however, the first one looks prettier and "more PHP5" to me!
Speaking of flexibility, the first one is certainly more flexible as well, as you can use that code with any object that implements `Traversable` and not just `mysqli_result`.

Comment: Philosophically, it seems cleaner to iterate over list elements then to test whether we're at the end of the list and then iterate to the next element, so I agree.

Answer (score 0):

### Iterating a query result set object via foreach:

1. More concise syntax.
2. No need to write/call iterated "_fetch" methods.
3. The ability to use "[array destructuring syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2943403%20array%20destructuring)" in the signature to narrow the row payload or otherwise manipulate value assignments.
   `foreach ($result as ['fav_column' => $fav]) { echo "$fav\n"; }`
4. Row data can only be accessed using array syntax with associative keys.
   It is trivial, though, to convert row arrays to row objects in the loop body.
   And arguably, you could nominate increasing numeric column aliases from `0` -- then the array could be considered "indexed" ...meh.
   `SELECT col_name AS '0', another_col AS '1' ...`
5. If a row "counter" variable is advantageous while iterating, declaring `$i` (or some other name) as the variable to hold the first level keys will conveniently perform the incrementation.
   `foreach ($result as $i => $row) { ... }`

### Iterating a query result set object via while:

1. Less concise syntax.
2. More versatile tooling to dictate the keys /data types (indexed, associative, or both), and the payloads depending on the fetch method mode ([there are many](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php#:%7E:text=Table%20of%20Contents)).
   `while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) { ... }` // indexed row data
   `while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) { ... }` // both indexed & assoc data
   `while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) { ... }` // rows as objects
3. If additional loop-breaking conditions are appropriate, then they can be cleanly baked into the `while()` condition.
   `while ($someFlag === true && $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ... }`
4. If a row counter variable is needed, it must be declared and incremented manually by some other process.
   `$i = 0; while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ... ++$i; }`

---

Ultimately, my advice would be to use a `foreach()` unless you have a sound reason to use `while()` with a `_fetch()` call.

---

Topical note: [Source](https://www.php.net/mysqli_result#:%7E:text=8.0.0,was%20implemented%20instead.)

> 8.0.0 mysqli_result implements IteratorAggregate now.
> Previously, Traversable was implemented instead.

Answer (score -2):

I found this:

[for vs foreach vs while which is faster for iterating through arrays in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852242/for-vs-foreach-vs-while-which-is-faster-for-iterating-through-arrays-in-php)

the answer states that a difference in speed is so minimal that hardly matters which you use.

I like using foreach loops to iterate over returned information because I have access to the keys and values, which can be handy depending on the needed use.

```
$returned = array(array("userName" => "Tim"),array("userName" => "Bob"), array("userName" => "Guy"));

foreach($returned as $L1)
{
  foreach($L1 as $L2 => $val)
  {
      if($L2 === "userName")
      {

         echo 'Hello: ' . $val . "<br />";

      }

  }

}
```

I guess it depends on what values you need, how much control you need, and where you need it.

Comment: how that differs from `while` and `each`

Comment: I was just stating what I like to use and offering what another post offered on speediness. Don't have a cow, lol.

Comment: At first I thought the link was useful, but the timing results probably do not apply to this situation: $result isn't an array, it is an object that understands `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`. Timing is probably dominated by that `fetch_assoc` per iteration, not by any loop overhead.